# NYC Citibike Demand demo data access error

Tags: python, h2o

The Notebook demo of [NYC Citibike Demand with Weather (Large)](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/demos/citi_bike_large.ipynb) can't be run locally due to errors accessing the Citibike datasets. When the following cell is run:

```
big_test =   [mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2013-07.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2013-08.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2013-09.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2013-10.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2013-11.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2013-12.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2014-01.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2014-02.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2014-03.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2014-04.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2014-05.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2014-06.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2014-07.csv"),
          mylocate("bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2014-08.csv")]

# ----------

# 1- Load data - 1 row per bicycle trip.  Has columns showing the start and end
# station, trip duration and trip start time and day.  The larger dataset
# totals about 10 million rows
print("Import and Parse bike data")
data = h2o.import_file(path=big_test)
```

The following error is output if data_source_is_s3 is set to true:

```
H2OResponseError: Server error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Error: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
  Request: GET /3/ImportFiles
    params: {'path': 's3n://h2o-public-test-data/bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2013-07.csv'}
```

and the following if data_source_is_s3 is set to False:

```
ValueError: File not found: bigdata/laptop/citibike-nyc/2013-10.csv
```

Comment: Which version of h2o?